# Preimage of 1 orthogonal to 1 for skew-symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, evolutionary-game-theory

$$
\newcommand{\1}{\mathbf{1}}
\newcommand{\im}{\text{Im }}
\newcommand{\Span}[1]{\langle #1 \rangle}
\newcommand{\orth}[1]{ #1^{\perp}}
$$

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ skew-symmetric matrix. Define $\1 := (1, \dots, 1)$ and assume that $A^{-1}(\1)$ is non-empty. Show that
$$
A^{-1}(\1) \subseteq \1^{\perp}
$$
Namely, if $Aq = \1$ then $q \cdot \1 = 0$

---

I checked this by hand in low dimension, but don't have much of an idea how to proceed generally. An attempt could be that
$$
Aq = \1 \Rightarrow Aq \cdot \1 = -q \cdot A\1 = n
$$
but not much from here.

The key step is probably that $\im{A} = \ker{A}^{\perp}$. This implies
$$
\begin{split}
\1 \in \im{A} &\iff \Span{\1} \subseteq \im{A}  \\
& \iff \orth{\Span{\1}} \supseteq \ker{A} \\
& \iff \forall q \in \ker{A}, \,  q \cdot \1 = 0
\end{split}
$$

The solution of the affine system $Aq = \1$ is given by a particular solution $+ \ker{A}$, so $q \cdot \1$ is at least constant on $A^{-1}(\1)$.

---

To give some context: this problem arises when one looks for *formal equilibria* in [Evolutionary Game Theory](https://www.mathi.uni-heidelberg.de/%7Edlegacci/research.php), namely points $q$ fulfilling $Aq \in \Span{\1}$ and $q \cdot \1 = 1$ for some matrix $A$. Those points can be used to construct [Hamiltonian functions](https://arxiv.org/abs/1404.5900) for a class of [evolutionary dynamics](https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.09173).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A\mathbf{q} = \mathbf{1} \Rightarrow A\mathbf{q} \cdot \mathbf{q}= \mathbf{1} \cdot \mathbf{q}$, but the LHS vanishes by antisymmetry.

Comment: This was utterly simple. Thanks